# No outline shown in Goclipse

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

Configured everything about go eclipse plugin, press Command-O, no outline can be shown. Anyone can help?

Mac
Eclipse version: Mars
JDK 1.8

Comment: This is not a question about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the tools for GoClipse.

In Eclipse go to: Window - Preferences - Go - Tools

These are tools that people developed and that can be integrated in Eclipse (and give the functionality you want).

To add them you'll have to download and install them and then add their path to Eclipse preferences.

For example, follow the instructions for [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode).